# Undo "don't show anymore" (translation from french) when rename in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Translation (from french) of the pop-up message :

> You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in
> this project of all references to the code element 'xxxx' ?

I ticked the checkbox and I answered "Yes" ("Oui" in french) in Visual Studio 2019. Now, each time I try to rename a class, VS change automaticly all references of the class in the project. It's a huge problem when many classes have the same name but not the same namespace.

How undo it and show the pop-up again ?

[image: pop-up when renaming]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get again the pop-up, you have to check the last checkbox in the list in Options --> Project & Solutions --> General.

Translation from french : "Prompt for symbolic renaming when renaming files"

[image: Visual Studio Options in french]